# The downvote for duplication culture of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, downvotes, duplicate-questions

As someone who is somewhat new to Stack Overflow and a beginner programmer I thought I would give a bit of feedback on a particular aspect.

I recently posted this question on Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637349/how-to-match-two-different-strings-with-one-if-statement

It got down voted and marked as a duplicate.

**Firstly**, the question that the duplication is marked to has a really unhelpful title that I could not hope to possibly link to my question through a search (Stack Overflow search seems to mainly consider the title).

**Secondly**, surely having questions worded differently will allow more people to find there answer quickly. A lot of beginners don't understand the technical terms and therefore can't effectively search. They generally search for their particular scenario. If more variants exist then more people would be attracted to Stack Overflow. The moderators wouldn't have as much work to do because beginners would always type new question as they can find exactly what they need.

**Thirdly**, The aggressive downvoting is very off putting. It makes Stack Overflow users look like snobs that say "If you can't understand whats going on then you shouldn't be here!" or "We don't want you here if you don't understand anything!". A simple marking of duplication will suffice.

This doesn't happen all the time. Stack Overflow is generally very helpful and informative, and I have found most questions are answered well. Does anyone else have the same opinion?

---

**Extra Thoughts:**
Having read people's feedback I just want to clarify that I don't mind the question getting closed for being a duplicate because that is what it is and it answers the question. My problem lies with down voting. I also understand that this is necessary but I think that it might be worth considering looking at ways to improve its usage.

One idea that might help new users would be to force people to give a reason for down voting (and maybe even upvoting). This would mean some effort would be required to perform this negative action but it would also build up the community as people would know why it is happening. In addition to helping the community the feedback could be subject to points/badges as well, to encourage this behavior. This would not just help beginner programmers but also would help experienced programmers that need help on how to right questions well. All this would be anonymous avoiding any revenge down votes.

A second idea would be to make a golden answer for frequent questions. Some peoples comments below seem to be along the lines of the are tired of seeing repeats of the same question. If the same question is repeated so often. They could make a perfect question/answer combo and use it with the duplication links. SO could also help track questions that occur a lot and help with tagging duplicates.

From reading comments I have also got the impression that this place is definitely not for newbies and that they don't seem to be encouraged to join. Is this the wrong sentiment that I am getting? I suppose the introduction does say *"Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers."*

Lastly, I think that the internal search function does need overhauled. It is not finding any examples similar to what I want. Only with hindsight on the problem can I seem to find the solution.

Comment: I have to admit that you are right for the "duplicate", the title is just garbage and your title is better. You should probably consider editing the original question to improve it ;)

Comment: @Theolodis Does SO have a downvote culture for bad titling? I really don't know the extensive list of reasons why things get downvoted.

Comment: FWIW, I would not call the 2 down votes that you had (prior to calling attention to yourself here) "aggressive down voting". I would call that "mild down voting".

Comment: @joran That was probably an exaggeration compared to the down votes some questions I have seen but to a new person it is still off putting that by the time you have even refreshed the page people have rejected what you have written.

Comment: I agree with the bad title and changed it to something more descriptive (*Can I check if multiple variables evaluate to a certain condition?*)

Comment: My point is simply that completely setting aside the merits of your question, the ability to brush off 1-2 votes (in either direction) is a necessary skill if you want to exist on SO (or the internet, frankly).

Comment: @joran I completely agree that every should be thick skinned on the internet but it doesn't mean we have to promote being aggressive. SO could be a lot more friendly and appealing to use.

Comment: Related: [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/456814).

Comment: For partial list of why questions get downvoted: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The other topics in the help center contain more reasons (off-topic, no minimally verifiable example, etc).

Comment: @Marmstrong the votes are used as positive and negative feedback and reinforcement for behavior. I'm ambivalent about the use in the case of duplicates though. If the asker was lazy and didn't even bother to try a few google queries or look in documentation, that could justify a downvote, but sometimes it can be hard to tell if that's the case, in my opinion. I've generally given up on downvoting questions, there's too much drama and confrontation that goes along with it `:/`

Comment: @Cupcake So presumably I got down vote for not doing enough research effor? How can someone really know how much effort was put in (apart from the the obvious scenarios)? Like I said in the question beginners don't know the technical jargon and therefore will spend a lot longer searching for answers than a more advanced person. Some problems also are so close or a deceptive that it may be hard to find. Often you could look at a problem for hours and not get an answer. It can only take a second pair of eyes seconds to spot the mistake.

Comment: @Marmstrong sorry, I don't have a clear answer for you. Like I said, I've given up on downvoting questions. It comes with too much trouble. I'm staying miles away from the whole practice.

Comment: @Marmstrong I go through and downvote questions which display no research effort, or when they're simply way too beginner-level for SO (based on my subjective judgment). My understanding is that SO is not the place for simple syntax / flow control questions from self-proclaimed "beginner programmers". Python, Perl, and PHP, in particular, have TONS of good resources for learning the basics of the language.

Comment: I want to reiterate that even after drawing attention to yourself on Meta, you have a grand total of 3 down votes and 1 up vote. You're making a mountain out of a mole-hill. Remember that you did get a good answer to your question, so it's not like the response you got was unhelpful. If you find a small number of down votes this upsetting, SO might not be a great place for you at the moment.

Comment: If you didn't like the title of the linked dupe, there are *literally thousands* of others to choose from; I would estimate that that question gets asked at least once a day on average.  We tend to use that one as the go-to dupe because it has a well written answer.

Comment: A downvote is a signal to other SO users that there is no need to pay attention to the question.  Which looks pretty accurate to me if your question was a duplicate.  You'll have to get used to the idea that votes are on questions, not persons.  Not being able to adapt to the SO ways of doing things is not a problem with SO, it really is your problem.  Nobody forces you to use it.

Comment: The fact that you wouldn't have known what to Google to find that question doesn't really matter, as long as the linked question does indeed solve your problem. Your second item here is right on: the post is now a pointer to the answer for people who use search terms similar to yours, and the solution information is kept in one place, rather than smeared out across dozens of threads, forum-style.

Comment: Stack Overflow gets 8,000 new questions every day and many of them are easily Googleable duplicates. There is nothing wrong with the culture of downvoting those (although of course great care must be used at all times.)

Comment: If your question is general here's my take: I've had my share of downvotes and I can understand the occasional 'harsh' feeling. Having said that, overall I think the culture has the correct attitude. If the tone wasn't a bit 'strict' the place would be almost immediately overrun with laziness. I have myself been guilty of this. Like even the best governments it sometimes gets a little too strict but on balance it works amazingly well.

Comment: In my mind there are two types of duplicates: 1) The OP put little or no (sometimes it even seems negative) effort into researching the problem.  These should be viciously downvoted and quickly closed as dupe.  2) The question is answered by another question (not necessarily easy to identify), so technically a dupe.  It is reasonable to mark such a question "dupe", I think, but it should not be downvoted.  However, I've also personally observed folks applying the first strategy to questions that clearly fall into the second category.  It's human nature.

Comment: (It is a valid complaint here that the search facilities really suck.  I find the best way to do a search is to begin editing a question and then, after typing a few lines, look at the list of "Questions that may already have your answer" displayed above the edit window.)

Comment: @HotLicks for your 2nd category of duplicate questions, I find it strange that we would downvote these. You know, the kind of questions that are phrased differently. We're actively encouraged to not delete these because they add more search keywords that lead to a canonical answer, and yet downvotes encourage the original poster to delete the duplicate. It's counter-productive.

Comment: Possibly related: [Getting to Know Stack Overflow's Voting Culture](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251487/456814).

Comment: I typed "python" followed by the exact question title into the google and got lots of useful hits - you could have easily done that. At least one of those hits is on this site.

Comment: @HansPassant The downvote is not just a signal to other SO users. If you look now at the voting on my original question you can see its receive a lot of different votes, both up and down. These votes where NOT cast to indicate the question wasn't good as it is far past being answered. Plus marking the question as duplicate puts the  words duplicate in the title. This is indication to people that the question can't be answered and doesn't need considered. Down votes are just redundant in this case.

Comment: Well so far you've gained 43 rep from the question, so don't be too unhappy

Comment: Your suggestion of anonymous commenting (to explain downvotes) will lead to more viciousness. The fact that you sign (often with a fictitious name, but at least as a "knowable entity") at least gives _some_ accountability to the person writing the comment.

Comment: @Cupcake - I agree the "type 2" questions should not be downvoted and deleted, but they are, quite regularly.  (But a rhetorical question for everyone: If one has tens of thousands of points, what are those points good for other than downvoting?)

Comment: Being a new guy myself, and one prone to make mistakes--even after doing a day's worth of research--I share @Marmstrong's sense of being scorned by anonymous downvotes. But I also understand the desire to maintain a high quality of discourse on SO. Seems like, with the technology available, and the obvious talent around here, that maybe a alternate system might be instituted. Sort of a "three strikes and then you start losing rep" scheme where you get a couple of warnings before you get pilloried. Also, a downvoter could be required to explain, maybe with a checklist. Anonymously, of course.

Comment: **(Ahem)** regarding anonymous explanations for downvotes, **Please Read** [Enable Optional Anonymous Reasons for Downvotes on Questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253531/456814), especially the "Related Posts" section at the bottom of the question. *This is a well-worn topic*.

Comment: See also [Replace the built-in Elastic Search with results from Google instead](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254093/456814).

Comment: That this was closed as a duplicate of a question that approaches from a completely different aspect--supporting your thesis almost perfectly--gave me the best laugh of the day.  The agressive closing of questions on SO is an aspect that is turning me into a hater.  People learn from answering at least as much as reading an answer.  Not that I have a problem with cross-linking to similar answers, but if it was REALLY a dupe than it was titled in such a way that this wasn't obvious so a second reference never hurts!

Comment: @BillK I got a lot of hate from posting this. People have gone through my questions and downvoted them. There is a lot of hate on SO.

Comment: @Marmstrong It involves "Winning" more than hating I think.  They have this closed view that everything must fit the model in their head (something very common amoung nerds who are generally correct about many things--we tend to think that only we are right about everything). As soon as you give the bullied some power their tendancy is to use it to treat others as they have been treated--I wouldn't take it personally.  I think I'm the hater because I see their behavior and know that I barely suppress the tendancy to be an ass myself. You most hate for behaviors which you dislike in yourself :)

Comment: So this has also been marked as a duplicate? ... priceless! :)

Comment: @Lankymart It is hilarious!! People also went through and downvoted a bunch of my questions. Talk about not being allowed to hold an opinion.

Comment: @Marmstrong I was being sarcastic (*sorry*)...but sad to hear you have fallen foul of [The Meta Effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect).

Comment: @Lankymart Not a worry. I am here to get my questions answered and to learn not to score virtual points on some website.

Comment: @Marmstrong I do understand your frustration but just for the record I do agree with the majority I'm afraid. It was a duplicate and the appropriate action was taken. In my experience most of the time it's best to just accept it and move on.

Comment: @Marmstrong I can't agree more with your "Thirdly" point as it happened to me many times and I felt unwanted, discouraged and misunderstood. And moreover, I felt my question was legitimate (and still do).

Comment: @MaximeBernard I have learned since posting this that SO can be very petty. Quite a lot of my questions got downvoted because I posted this. I now just use this place to get my questions answered and get out as quickly as I can. I ignore all the other stuff that happens around. Its a bit sad really considering how good this place could actually be.

Comment: much later: the dup question now has a very understandable title that makes sense (which now makes this meta question confusing at first)

Answer (score 92):

Let's visit the duplicate, shall we. Now forget about the duplicate itself. Look at the Linked list to the right of it:

> [image]

There are 149 questions linked to it in total. I didn't go through all 149, but plenty of those are duplicates of that exact same question and have been closed as such. So we're not exactly talking an obscure duplicate.

[A few duplicates are no problem.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) As you say yourself, a bit of duplication can be entirely helpful. But there comes a point where those active in the tag think "not this again". And while that's entirely my personal interpretation of the 3 (yes, only 3) downvotes you have received so far, if you've seen the same question being asked time and time again, a downvote is justifiable. And calling it "aggressive" is an exaggeration.

> "If you can't understand whats going on then you shouldn't be here!" or "We don't want you here if you don't understand anything!"

Especially considering duplicates, that interpretation of downvotes makes no sense whatsoever. At the most the downvotes indicate you should perhaps (re)search a bit more before asking a question. You might not find the canonical duplicate, but you will at some point hit upon a question that is closed as a dupe of it.

That you might have to search a bit more is also the worst the downvotes should indicate to you. Anything beyond that is your own interpretation. Most important, downvotes are not personal. Don't interpret them as such and your life on the site will be a whole lot easier.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that one need not wait until after posting to check that list off to the right. As you are composing a question, SO dynamically updates a list of questions that its algorithms think are related (and possibly duplicate). It's worth perusing the list before hitting the "Post Your Question" button.

Comment: @TedHopp Right, when I am writing a question I type there, doing my best to make the title meaningful and concise. 99/100 there is already a question / answer and I was making a duplicate, it is extremely useful.

Comment: `But there comes a point where those active in the tag think "not this again"` - exactly. I've seen a variation of this question about 5 times this month already...

Comment: @TedHopp Every time I right a question I always check the related questions that SO offer and only post if there doesn't appear to be any duplication. Too be honest I don't find it works very well.

Comment: @Marmstrong - I've found that unless the question contains lots of keywords in the text itself, the system often works poorly until I add tags to my draft. Then the results improve considerably.

Comment: @TedHopp In my experience it seems to go a lot of what is placed in the title. As I have said above a newbie won't know the keywords. I have also now learned the best thing would be to google it as this will parse through the actual text of the question.

Comment: @Marmstrong Originally it does and the results aren't often relevant for me just based off the title.  However, it updates as I write my question body, and by the time I'm mostly done writing my question, the results are much more relevant - more often than not I find a duplicate (even with a completely different title).

Comment: @TedHopp I usually write my question first and then the title depending on the way I have worded my question. SO doesn't offer suggestions until the title is entered and they are never good. Does the order affect this?

Comment: @Marmstrong Try entering tags first, then the title. It seems that suggested duplicates are retrieved with tags in the query.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to reduce the list after the fact with a decent search engine rather than unleashing a bunch of self-important over-empowered nerds like me to arbitrarially downvote and close questions based on our personal viewpoints (I've seen questions, for instance, asked and answered by beginners that were much more searchable and understandable (by beginners) than the question they were linked to.  It would have hurt no-one, ever, to leave both open.

Answer (score 35):

When I see obvious duplicates like this, I want to warn my fellow programmers that this isn't a question worth their time. Downvotes will communicate to the other users that this may not be worth their time, and they'll skip it and answer another question instead.

Secondly, IIRC, downvotes will push the question down on the *Interesting* tab, and the chance that high-rep users gets tired and bails on SO because of all the dupes and noise, is slightly lowered if they don't see the question at all.

I don't care much about if the newbie python-user gets "put off" by it - he'll most likely just contribute with noise anyway for a long time, so it's not a big loss for the community if he stays away for a while.

Comment: At least you called it as you see it. This brings up the third comment I said in the original question.

Comment: Would anyone be willing to make a stack overflow for beginners then?

Comment: @marmstrong I think your missing the point. SO is for all users with questions that can add to the community as a whole. A 'similar' question is at the moderator's discretion to close as a duplicate and I'm fine with that as long as they do so with the communities best interest's in mind.

Comment: @TheJavaBeast I completed understand and agree with that. Marking as duplicate also answers my question which is why I wrote the question. The down voting I think could be handled differently though. My problem is not with the duplication close but with the down voting. (I have commented on the original question to indicate this.)

Comment: @Marmstrong in general the voting is the best feature of SO, and there is little they can do to enforce why someone chooses to down vote. Perhaps the only thing they could do is provide a separate vote feature to mark the originality of the question which could segregate the votes more. But even still I'm fine with the way things are.

Comment: @TheJavaBeast From reading the commments I think most people are happy with the way things are as well. What did you think about my suggestion to provide feedback when a person is downvoting. It would save people asking "why is this getting downvoted?"

Comment: @Marmstrong Downvotes are a tool to help the community rather than to harm the asker. Downvoting is anonymous because there actually are spiteful people around ready to engage in revenge downvoting. That being so, for the good of the site it is better to live with the occasional unfair downvote rather than scaring people out of downvoting. A secondary issue is that if everyone had to explain downvotes with comments there would be duplication and noise whenever two people downvoted for the same reason.

Comment: @Marmstrong STOP taking downvotes personally. Just stop. All of us receive downvotes. It is not a bad thing. Negative feedback is very useful. Learn from it, be happy about it. Stop whining, please. This place is very fruitful for beginners, but if you think a beginner should only receive nice words, maybe this place is simply not for you. I was a beginner when I came here and some really strict people here helped me the most.

Comment: @kapa Downvotes is not negative feedback. It does tell you what you have done wrong only that the question is not to be considered by the general masses of SO. I agree strictness needs to be kept. The site can not accept the lowest standard of question.

Comment: @duplode I hadn't thought about the anonymity aspect of down votes. This makes little difference to the original idea though, all the written feedback would be anonymous as well.

Comment: If you find a question which you believe is a duplicate, the proper action is to close it as a duplicate, given that you have enough rep to cast close votes (you do). If you can't be bothered to find a duplicate, then fine, leave the question behind, maybe someone else will do it. A silent down vote is not in the slightest helpful in this case, especially not if the question is otherwise fine.

Comment: @Lundin As I wrote above, the *silent down vote* **is** helpful for other users - it signals that the Q isn't worth opening.

Answer (score 15):

Move your mouse over the down-vote button and you will see a tool-tip. The tool-tip will give lack of research effort as a reason to down-vote. A duplicate question always carries with it the suspicion that the asker did not do enough research *to search for existing equivalent questions*. I suggest that is why you see down-votes for duplicates.

How much research effort is enough? Remember, the asker is expecting strangers to provide expert advice for free. So expecting the asker to spend *much more* time researching the question than an expert would take to answer it is reasonable.

So one or two Google searches didn't find an answer? Not enough research, if you are a beginner. Because you might have to study a text book, or talk to your teacher. Ironically, experts asking fellow experts can do less searching, because their expertise enables them to formulate good searches. Google and SO are therefore rather poor means for answering *very* basic questions, by those new to programming.

Comment: How can someone really know how much effort was put in (apart from the the obvious scenarios)? Like I said in the question beginners don't know the technical jargon and therefore will spend a lot longer searching for answers than a more advanced person. Some problems also are so close or a deceptive that it may be hard to find. Often you could look at a problem for hours and not get an answer. It can only take a second pair of eyes seconds to spot the mistake. Books may not always help and you may not be near someone to help.

Comment: @Marmstrong That would be part of being an expert. Research effort is not measured simply in time. The effort has to be in some activity that is likely to be fruitful.

Comment: @Marmstrong It has been said before: SO is not a substitute for teachers and text books. Nor is it a remote debugging service.  Expecting it to act as a second pair of eyes suggests you believe it ought to be.

Comment: @Raewald You have made it clear in every other word apart from saying it that beginners are not welcome and that this is for "Experts" only. All effort is subjective. You could say your "Experts" should know where to look to find there answers and therefore, shouldn't need SO. I was told previously that SO should be a repository of knowledge all question types and levels should be welcome if this is to be achieved.

Comment: @Marmstrong You are twisting my words. No, research effort is not subjective. No, not *all* questions are welcome: that is why questions can closed and deleted.

Comment: I didn't mean to come across that I was twisting your words but thats they way your comment sounded like. I completely agree not all questions should be accepted, hence the need for down votes but I disagree about the research effort not being subjective.

Comment: @Marmstrong In the rules of football, law 12 specifies that an offence is committed by a player which is not a goalkeeper who "handles the ball deliberately". If being "subjective" in the sense you are using was enough to invalidate a justification for applying a rule, then football referees would not be able to punish players who handle the ball, as "objectively" detecting whether an action was deliberate would, in the general case, require mind reading.

Comment: @Marmstrong - "experts should know where to look[...]shouldn't need SO ". Yes they do know where to look. They look here, on SO. And will find their question already answered, most of the time.

Comment: @duplode This is an example of a question that should be down voted for not showing research effort. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356501/how-do-you-round-up-a-number-in-python . You can quite easily look up this in a book or google it yet it has recieved up votes. It is very subjective and to my mind it seems people have got more cynical in down voting questions like these.

Comment: @Marmstrong No, that is a good example of a question **showing** research effort. Note that the asker demonstrates that they have tried various promising looking methods, `round()` and `int()`, without success, and has something that works except for edge cases. The question is not at all subjective: it has an objective answer.

Comment: Just because someone tried a couple things doesn't mean the asker put in any effort. Typing "round up python" in google would have got you exactly what you need. You are being subjective in suggesting that he did put in appropriate effort.

Comment: @Marmstrong I tried doing a Google search typing in the title of the post you linked to (i.e. I did research effort!), and it does not appear this answer is "easily" looked up.  I see a lot of links about how to round down (the opposite of the question), and a few links where someone else asked how to round up but the answers didn't seem to answer that.  I don't know Python so I may have missed something.  Nevertheless I think there's too much assumption out there that if a question is trivial to us it must therefore be easily Googlable.

Comment: @Marmstrong I guess you don't really want to understand what "research effort" means. You just want to whine because you got some down-votes.

Comment: @ajb Exactly, so research effort is completely subjective.

Comment: @Marmstrong Sure, whether it appears sufficient research was done *is* subjective.  That in no way means it's an inappropriate guidelines for evaluating posts.  Whether a post is "clear" is subjective, whether a post is "useful" is subjective.  *All* metrics for evaluating a post are subjective.  That doesn't make them bad or wrong.  It means that readers of a post need to make judgment calls about their evaluation of a post when providing feedback.  You seem to be equating "subjective" with "wrong", and that's just not the case.

Answer (score 6):

You're right about the utility of different wordings of what are, at root, the same questions. But that's actually why closing a question as a duplicate can be *good*. By closing as a duplicate the different wording can link to a (more) canonical answer, which is the primary purpose of this site – generating canonical answers to programming questions.

Unfortunately, there's no clear consensus on how, or how best, to help new users, or new programmers, ask better questions. As you pointed out, oftentimes the people asking these questions don't even know the right terms or phrases to use when searching for answers! I am a little saddened to admit that those people are not the appropriate audience for this site. As much as it would be nice to educate them, it's an overwhelming and therefore impossible task. And, as you've surely detected, there's a lot of bitterness among expert and knowledgeable users about the extremely high ratio of 'noise' versus 'signal' in terms of question quality.

The reason why it's appropriate to downvote duplicates is that users are expected to know enough already about the area for which they're asking questions to find any existing questions that are similar enough to be considered a duplicate. It's inevitable that many people will consider any downvote as a form of punishment; I've certainly felt that way myself.

As much as I and others might want there be someway to encourage and help people that aren't capable of asking good questions, there's currently no way to do so as part of this site itself.

Comment: See me edits in the original question about some of what you have to say. Maybe a way would be to give a reason with your down vote and maybe give an example of what to do instead. These suggestions can then get the sharer points/badges.

Comment: `As much as I and others might want there be someway to encourage and help people that aren't capable of asking good questions, there's currently no way to do so as part of this site itself.` There is. They are called comments. You have the option to explain to the OP exactly what they did wrong so they do not repeat the same mistake again. It's your choice whether or not to use that tool.

Comment: @mbs, the comments aren't a *practical* means by which to "explain to the OP *exactly* what they did wrong", as doing so *exactly* is almost always an *exacting* task. What a lot of these OPs really need is to have their question moved to a forum and to have helpful people point out each of their misconceptions and misunderstandings, and point them towards available resources to alleviate both, some of which may in fact be good SO questions. That's not practical in comments and it's discouraged to boot; I have to agree that it's not really appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

This, from the guy that helped create SO (emphasis is mine):

'Every question in Stack Overflow is like the Wikipedia article for some extremely narrow, specific programming question. How do I enlarge a fizzbar without overwriting the user’s snibbit? *This question should only appear once in the site. Duplicates should be cleaned up quickly and redirected to the original question.*' ` Joel Spolsky

[Joel Spolsky's blog at Joel On Software](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html)

Comment: I agree but they shouldn't be down voted. That is where the problem is. Down voting achieves NO BENEFIT other than having the question deleted and creating bad will. Marking as duplicate lets others know it shouldn't be considered for answering and stops the asker reaping any benefit and also answers the question (asker should follow the link). Having the duplicate stay open is good (see point two in the original question).

Comment: I agree with your stance on down-voting, with regards to your original question.  Simply marking it as duplicate seems the better idea.

Comment: Try and convincing others here is hard. They are really stuck in there ways and don't want to change a thing. Not everyone, only some. Reading around the Meta this sort of idea and stance occurs quite often but tends to get bashed down.

Comment: @Marmstrong Downvoting those questions that are poorly researched, and are using SO as a human search engine because they can't be bothered to run their question through Google *are causing major problems for the site*.  The downvote are accurately reflecting the feedback that those questions are of low quality and are harmful to the site.  Closing the question also *doesn't* stop the author from reaping benefits. Closed questions can still be upvoted.  Second *their getting an answer to the question that they should have just searched for*. We don't want to encourage that behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Closing a duplicate is ok, because the question then sticks around as a stub for future searchers.  What's wrong is deleting it, since then that stub is gone.

It's also not good to downvote a question just because it's a duplicate.  While people are free to downvote as they please, the reason for downvoting should be because it is a poor question, not because it is a duplicate.

Comment: I agree. Down votes encourage duplicates being deleted but this leads to a lack of scenario diversity (point two in my original question) which is something that SO should desire.

Comment: One official reason for downvoting is lack of research effort.

Comment: The vast majority of duplicate questions are *not* valuable windows into the canonical post, and leaving them around isn't actually helping people find the canonical duplicate.  Some do indeed use different terminology, and help someone find an answer when they otherwise wouldn't.  Those are worth keeping around.  For these remaining dupes that don't use different terminology, and don't already have a lot of google juice or incoming links, they may as well just be deleted.

Comment: I think it's a good point - who WOULDN'T be tempted (among new users) to delete a post that has been downvoted AND marked as a duplicate?  The 'duplicate' process exists for a reason, and it does NOT delete the question (merely closes it)... I'm not sure what kind of a solution there could be though.  If we made duplicates immune to downvoting it could result in an abundance of extremely low quality posts.  Perhaps we could have options to flag a post as a duplicate, both with/without nomination to delete (new voting), while protecting duplicate-marked posts from hurting hapless posters' rep.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow is a site for **programmers**. It was started by a leading programmer bringing along his blog readers that were all expert programmers.

If you ask a question that shows you have not even bothered to read a basic programming book, don't expect people to be nice to you.

I have seen much worse questions than yours. However, the site was "sold" to expert programers as a site for expert programmers, so some users still expect the same standard.

Comment: Where is it written that SO is for "expert programmers"?

Answer (score 3):

The proper action to do as a reader when you encounter a potential duplicate, is to cast a close vote and link a duplicate post. If you can't be bothered to find a duplicate, or if you don't have enough rep to cast close votes, then leave the question as it is.

We have to keep in mind that not everyone is an experienced user of the site, nor experienced enough about programming to determine whether their question is a FAQ or not. Therefore, silent down votes for a duplicate with no explanation given are not helpful. They are actually quite harsh.

*However*, we *should* down vote duplicates where the question is such an obvious FAQ that minimum research effort would have revealed the answer. There are perhaps around 5 to 10 different questions per programming language that keep coming back very frequently, on almost daily basis. It is very easy to find the answer to those with minimum research effort. So those questions should get closed and down voted both.

As for this specific case, I know too little of Python to tell whether it is a very frequently asked question or not. The ["frequent" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) of the Python tag seems to suggest that this might be the case. In fact, the exact duplicate appears as number 6 in the SO Python FAQ. So the down votes may actually be justified in this specific case; you could likely have done more research before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I am thankful for the fact that many questions get closed as duplicates. I use this site mostly for researching issues at work and many times I just need a **good** quick answer. Typically with duplicate questions there is 1 original with many high quality answers and many duplicates with low quality answers.

Even if questions are not identical, by identifying questions that *are similar enough* and closing them SO can provide searchers with a quick link to the **main** question with all the good answers.

Maybe what they should do is have a vote button to re-open a question, but i have rarely found a closed question that didn't have a much better one linked to it.

Comment: Agian I agree. One good answer is all that is needed and all the duplicates should point to this one good golden answer but a diversity of way of asking the question should be desired (point two in the original question) and down voting encourages deleting these questions. Also the question that was put forward as the duplicate of mine had a rubbish title. The golden answer that is linked should have a clear and concise question as well. Maybe questions that come up frequently should have a standard question answer created and that is linked instead?

Comment: The fact about a similar question with a more direct title is a good point, but really what would the solution be if thats where the good answers are? If nothing else someone would locate your question (with the better title) and be linked to the lesser titled question with answers. Sure not perfect, but under those conditions its about as good as I could imagine

Comment: I would have deleted my better titled question because it had too many down votes only I want to make a point here. Which means down votes are counter productive in this scenario (duplication).

Comment: This meta question is about downvoting, not whether or not the posts should be closed as a duplicate, and your answer doesn't address that.  Questions also *can* be reopened.  That feature has been around since the site was created.