# I cannot ask questions on Stack Overflow even after I edited my questions. What do I do?

Tags: support, post-ban

I posted a question on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't put up any images due to my reputation points being under 10.  People were downvoting me because I didn't have photos, but I wasn't allowed to post photos.  The question ended up getting removed before I could host them on another site and post then (which is what people told me to do in the comments).

Long story short... I cannot ask questions anymore (I asked another question that got downvoted a lot) and I don't know what to do.  I read the help center page and they said to edit the past question so it was acceptable.  The question that I couldn't post pictures too has been edited and updated so now the images are on there and it is a good question.

I deleted the other question I got downvoted for because people said I could find that information on the web (which I researched for before asking the question)... So there wasn't much sense in editing it because they thought it was a bad question.

Can anyone help?  This all just seems a bit... I don't know... Aggressive?

I just read this post and someone gave some insight in how to get their account back.  This person had a lot more penalties than I did, so I am confused as to why this happened.

EDIT:
This post that is right above mine is right inline with my thinking...
[The downvote for duplication culture of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254712/the-downvote-for-duplication-culture-of-stack-overflow)

Comment: Let me clarify.  For example, in the question that Bart posted it states, "If you're trying to get a ban lifted, the most important thing to do is to transform posts that were not well received into posts that are well received by the community, i.e. humans. This transformation should, in the long run, garner positive votes on said posts (a sign that people find them useful), which is (probably) the most important factor in the decision to automatically lift a ban or not. "

I transformed my posts to be good already, but am still banned.

Comment: You've only got two questions; chances are pretty good you have deleted questions that are keeping you in the ban.

Comment: I only have one deleted question.  This question was not accepted by the community because they thought I could find the information elsewhere.  However, I did prior research and could not find any information regarding it.  With this being said, the community didn't like the question as a whole, so editing it wouldn't make a difference.  This is why I deleted it.  Again, that is the only deleted question I have.

Comment: Do you have a link to the deleted question? (You can find it through the "Recent Deleted Questions" link on your Questions tab on your profile)  It seems unlikely that a single deleted question (and one Q with 1 downvote, and one Q with 1 upvote) could lead to a ban, but perhaps a moderator could confirm.

Comment: It has 7 downvotes... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527270/what-can-classes-do-that-ids-cannot-do  Again, I researched it but couldn't find any answers that were clear enough for me to understand.

Comment: This is the error I receive when I try to post a question: "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."

Comment: You're sure you don't have any other deleted questions? (You checked "Recent Deleted Questions" under your Questions tab?)

Comment: Just scrolled down and realized that I did have another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505829/how-to-remove-footer-from-web-page). However, this question and the one where I ask about the lines are a result of the same problem.  I couldn't post images, so I could not appropriately explain what the problem was.  Is there a way to merge the question about the lines and the question above?  At the time I did not realize that I was supposed to edit the question in order to make it understandable, otherwise I would have not posted this question. I still learning how to use SO.

Comment: If I come across a (mildly) interesting question where the picture actually is *useful* -- never mind the n00bs that post images of source code or error messages! -- I may inline it for new users. Purely as a welcoming service.

Comment: I was unable to post pictures due to my reputation score being below 10.

Comment: You could have posted it on an image sharing site like imgur and added a link.

Comment: In any case- if you can improve the other deleted question you can flag it and ask a moderator to undeleted it

Comment: Right.  I didn't realize I could do that as I did not think about it.  Some forums don't let you post urls when you're a beginner too, so maybe I automatically ruled it out of my mind due to that...

Comment: @DavidRobinson I edited the question so it is much more clear.  I flagged it for a mod to see, but I haven't heard from anyone for about 24 hrs.  Is there someone I can message to have them check it out?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I got upvote on my questions and still I got blocked on stackoverflow. Why is it so?

Comment: I am facing same problem any way to get it enabled /un banned ?