# Improvement to the search function

Tags: discussion, search

When I look for previously answered questions on a problem of mine I do the following:

1. "Ask Question"
2. use broad title and relevant tags
3. throw some buzzwords in body
4. scroll "Similar questions" / "Questions that may already have your answer"-sections for hits

This usually gives very accurate hits in short time

Why do I do this, rather than use (Advanced) search?

- Results update as you type => realtime feedback if you're "getting there"
- tags are actaully "tagged" => see if this tag is good
- more precise than advanced search, esp with time-aspect
- way easier to convert into an actual question when nothing relevant shows up

**Question:**
Would it be possible to alter the search function to use similar a similar interface?

Comment: Could be an improvement, but I prefer [Replace the built-in Elastic Search with results from Google instead](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254093/replace-the-built-in-elastic-search-with-results-from-google-instead) to be implemented.

Comment: @Stijn I think these two add up to each other in that the search should be reworked to be more dynamic.