# Search not finding the obvious

Tags: bug, search

I have always been quite happy with SO search, but this one caught me by surprise. Searching for a post I knew existed, by almost the exact name, and filtering by the not very populated subject, failed:

Here is the search:

[image]

And this is the post I think it should have found:

[How do I install the latest version of rgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142762/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-rgl)

Bug, feature, or user error?

And it occurs to me now, do I get maybe another hat for this questions?

Comment: It is the "to" keyword that is messing it up. No idea why.

Comment: Replacing "to" with "do I" in the search query makes the question show up. (That, of course, doesn't make it any less surprising.)

Comment: I cannot believe people use in-site search anywhere unless for very site-specific functionality (all products in a certain category with < 24 hour delivery, all posts by a certain user, ...). Search is _hard_ to get right. Just use your favorite web search engine and append "site:stackoverflow.com" to your query.

Comment: I've learned to never use our own local search we use google.  Elastic search or search for that matter is not easy and has never worked really well.  There is little to no help available either and not a lot of people are elastic search experts.

Comment: I find limiting the scope with the tag (like [rgl]) is a huge help, and gives me better results than google. But this one threw me. Could be because searching for "r" or "shiny" gets a lot of noise on google.

Comment: A bug, closed as a duplicate of a feature request, closed as a duplicate of a support inquiry? Something has gone badly wrong here. Every time a problem with search is brought up, it gets closed as a duplicate of a support question that says "use teh Google". That's a perfectly valid answer to a support question, but not a valid answer to a feature request or bug report. If we're going to *have* a search feature and not simply outsource it to Google, it is probably beneficial to ensure that it does not suck.

Comment: @CodyGray I opted for closing it as a duplicate that one because they're both asking pretty much the same, the tags don't matter. I figured it'd be more clear than closing it as a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: @CodyGray There also happens to be [a feature request to replace the built-in Elastic Search with results from Google instead](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254093/247702), but a proper implementation would cost quite a bit of money: [2000 USD for 500k queries per year, for over 500k you need to contact sales](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4542048?hl=en&ref_topic=4513870).

Comment: They don't want it to be better, or even functionnal, or comparable to a real search engine, google will still be better even if they invest effort in fixing/upgrading it.

Comment: The important thing is that the site needs a search feature... that the search feature isn't particularly useful for the most common usage is dismaying... but we cannot scrap it, due the advanced search queries that we can use.

Comment: I suppose in general this is a good reminder that it's easy to be **overspecific** with search terms. Trim out the common fluff words, and a search of just `install latest version rgl` would have gotten you the right result.

Comment: But hey @Thriggle have you seen the part of my question that says :  `even noticed that removing the .NET will narrow the search from 44 results to 20... I don't quite understand again` so removing a word actualy narrowed the search...