# Should I edit titles which have nothing to do with the actual problem?

Tags: discussion, edits, title

I keep running into questions titles which may be potentially interesting, but then the problem is actually about a syntax, or some other basic error.

For example, I assumed  [scalar-product-of-vectors-two-in-nasm-and-c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23481139/10396), might have an interesting assembly code challenge.   However, it turned out the real 'question' was "I have some syntax errors but I don't know why."

If it was a pure 'gimme-teh-codez' question, I'd have no hesitation voting to close it. 
But sometimes the problem is actually instructive.  In this case, the assembler's preprocessor behavior can cause non-obvious syntax errors.  However,

- The question has absolutely nothing to do with vector products, so it's useless to people who find it in a title search.
- People who are trying to solve similar syntax errors won't ever find this solution.

In these cases, does it make sense to change the questions title to something like "Syntax Error in NASM", or "Why does NASM say 'comma or end of line expected'" or some such?   Or are these titles even less useful?

Comment: I do this all the time. I highly recommend it. It helps people find questions ***that are relevant to their own problems***. What's the point of searching for a problem about vectors and assembly, when the solution it contains is really for a different problem entirely?

Comment: I'm just afraid that 'Syntax Error' is equally useless as a title.  How would you title this one?

Comment: @AShelly: usually close as typo and it'll get deleted eventually.

Comment: @Mat, I don't want to delete it.  I want to salvage the useful part, which is "what is the non-obvious cause of this syntax error".

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with assembly and C to advise. However, here's my own example. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4061481/456814) was once titled "git push tag -> master", which attracted a bunch of "answers" about how to push tags with git, even though that's ***egregiously unrelated to the actual problem in the question***. I re-titled it to what the actual problem was, "Overwrite a branch with a tag by force-pushing it?".

Comment: @AShelly: then describe the error in the title in as few words as possible, including a short code expression if that fits.

Comment: OK, done. (5 more chars)

Comment: Just an observational note, I find that most people are frequently ***terrible*** at giving their questions good, descriptive titles, even if the rest of their question is relatively well-put `:P`

Comment: I had to edit the title here to make it a touch clearer

Comment: What's with the non-questions lately? *Of course you should edit titles that have nothing to do with the question as written*. I mean, what did you expect?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146975/should-question-titles-be-adjusted-to-actual-cause-of-a-problem

Comment: @Cupcake: That's mostly because naming things is one of the two hard problems in computer science, along with fast reliable cache invalidation and prevention of off-by-one errors.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## YES.

The question's title (and the body, too) should describe the *actual* problem, regardless of how the original poster viewed, framed, or described it. If the problem appeared to be one thing at first, but the answers reveal it to be something else, edit the question to reflect that.

Keep in mind that the page is going to be around for a long time, and it's going to come up in Google searches for years after the original posting time. Few things are as frustrating as searching for a problem, seeing a page title that matches precisely, and then finding that the actual error is completely unrelated to your own.

See also [Changing the title of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152252) on Meta.SE. Also see also [How to save the world... One question title at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201940/how-to-save-the-world-one-question-title-at-a-time)

Comment: It depends, having the text of an error message that can be goggled for in  a title can be very useful, even when the error message is not describing the “root” problem.

Comment: Yes, the error message itself, or some portion thereof, often makes a good title; I'm saying that if the error message is _unrelated to_ the actual problem and its solution, it shouldn't be in the title. The example at the end of this Meta question is without question a good edit.

Comment: +1, but *appeared to be one thing at first, but the answers reveal it* I'd rather take extra care with this one. Keeping the title approachable even if one doesn't already know the solution.

Comment: I think titles of **duplicate** questions can be alternative approaches to some 'more canonical' problem, in which case the duplicates' titles may be best as left alone.

Comment: I agree about duplicate titles, @naxa. With that sentence, I'm talking about a situation more like this: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25394040/revisions, where the title refers to a _task_, but the body is asking about an _error_. There are no answers there, I know. I can't find an example right now, but it occasionally happens that the answer is the thing that reveals the asker's true problem that way.

Answer (score 20):

Absolutely, you should edit titles to make them easier to understand by people who are searching for the questions.

If the question is indeed a closeworthy question, it's still relevant to edit the title, if only to draw reviewers who are more familiar with the topic of the question.  These will tend to be better reviewers.  Then you can vote to close.