# What should I do when the question is a dupe BUT also can be answered with "what you did wrong"?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I just ran into a situation I'm unclear of how to resolve in the best way:

This question: [subtract two arrays in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677582/subtract-two-arrays-in-perl?noredirect=1#comment36376154_23677582) - is really 2 questions in one:

- Stated question (How do I do X) - is a duplicate of an older question
- UN-stated - but very clear - question ("I wrote code Y to do X and it didn't work: **Why**?") is a pretty good question in its own right.

I have 2 options:

1. Close the question as a duplicate (I have gold-tag binding close vote); and asnswer the "what did I do wrong" in comments.

   This is what I've done now.
2. Don't close the question yet; post my answer of what did he do wrong - which seems pretty useful - as an answer - and THEN close the question as a duplicate.

#2 seems kind of hypocritical; but IMHO is better for the future readers who get the benefit of my explanation of why the OP made a subtle mistake.

Comment: Answering the question and then using your binding vote seems wrong. If it's a duplicate, mark it as a duplicate. If the original post doesn't contain the relevant information, I would add an answer to that.

Comment: @Joe - it's not that there's no "relevant information", it's that the current post has a second dimension ("why didn't this code work as expected?") that has NOTHING to do with the original post

Comment: I get that, but surely the OP could work out why his code didn't work as expected once presented with the correct solution?

Comment: @Joe - No he could not, as a matter of fact. "Correct", or rather canonical, solution is not even remotely related to his code. His code is also "Correct" (but different - it happens in Perl, a lot) but had a subtle bug. It may have helped if you read the linked question and comments.

Comment: If it's not a true duplicate, then it's not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I edit titles which have nothing to do with the actual problem?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254216/should-i-edit-titles-which-have-nothing-to-do-with-the-actual-problem)

Comment: @JoshCaswell - the title DOES have to do with an actual problem The issue is, his post is really 2 separate questions in one (the title reflectes one of the 2).

Comment: If I ask you, "How do I get to Detroit? My square wheels don't turn", the actual problem is my square wheels, not the route I'm planning. Fix the actual problem and edit the question to correctly reflect it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - Um. No. The equivalent is "What's the way to get to Detroit by car? I took highway #1 and then left on highway #2 and am lost". He has 2 problems: First, if he's going down highway #2, he should have turned right. Second, taking Highway #3 is the usual and faster route (but not the only correct one). So his question really has 2 answers: 1) To get to Detroit NOW and get unlost, turn right instead of left on Highway #2; 2) In the future, take Highway #3, it's better.

Comment: Doesn't sound like it's a duplicate, then.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - the first question is a duplicate... second isn't. And they are both bundled up (validly - he was actually doing the right thing and trying to solve himself and showing his work) in the same question

Comment: Definitely answer it if you can.

Comment: You could close it as a duplicate, and write a comment about the specific error he made.

Comment: @Barmar - That's exactly what I did. It's amazing that nobody commenting actually bothered glancing at the linked question.

Comment: You can also answer the unique question, and in your answer when you mention the attempted approach isn't the best, link to the older question as a source of information on the better approach.