# Encouraging titles relevant to the actual *problem*

Tags: discussion, title

Reading [Should I edit titles which have nothing to do with the actual problem?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254216/should-i-edit-titles-which-have-nothing-to-do-with-the-actual-problem) (to which the unequivocal answer is YES) - I can't help but think better titles can be better encouraged.

When asking a question, the prompt is:

> What's your programming question? Be specific.

I don't think it's surprising that, as per above linked question, there are many low-quality titles that describe the *situation* instead of the *problem*.

e.g. "Issue using feature x in library y", when the actual problem is "accessing structure members", for example.

---

I think maybe the language could be improved to avoid this - of course, it can still be ignored, but it could surely help.

An improvement *might* (this is a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion)) be "What's your programming question? State the issue you are experiencing.", for example.

Comment: I suspect nothing can be done for the numerous "please debug my program" questions. If the poster knew that their `NullPointerException` was more important than that they are trying sort an array (for example) and so should be in the title, they would already know how to debug the problem themselves.

Comment: Ironically, I misunderstood the title of *this* question, and thought that it was a proposal to introduce a new "titles" system to replace [tag badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395), with users being labeled "King Python", "Lord jQuery", or "Flight Sergeant C++" as their rep increased...