# Should a post title be modified to fit the problem?

Tags: discussion, title

### Motivation

Post titles are sometimes misleading because they do not summarize the problem well. Good titles should be concise, specifc and summarize the problem. Questions with good titles are more likely to be found by someone having the same problem and are also more likely to be answered by people who have the specific knowledge.

### Typical Scenario

A user asks something like (usually more sloppy...)

> How can I identify the ListView items uniquely when they only have a
>   non-unique name?

[The solution would be for example to set the ListViewItem Tag property for identification purpose.]

But the title for the post is something like

> Using mouse click event to get ListViewItem text

Which does not summarize the problem well at all. The problem the user was facing was not that he could not get the ListItem's text but he could not tell the items apart.

### Question

Is it valid to modify the post title to better match the actual problem?
A better title in above scenario would be for example:

> How to identify ListView items

This question was motivated by answering the following question: [Using mouse click event to get ListViewItem text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288625/using-mouse-click-event-to-get-listviewitem-text/27288897#27288897)

Comment: If the OP has no idea what his real problem is, it usually is an under-researched question.

Comment: I often do this ([see e.g. this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27261578/revisions)), mostly on questions that in essence are useful/good, and if the edit's substantial I give a friendly ping to the OP in comments. *Nearly* without exception I've receieved good, friendly, and thankful responses.

Comment: The only reason I often have doubts about these changes, is because of SEO reasons. Others with similar problems may be using the "crappy" title's terms in searches. The easy solution is usually available though: keep the "crappy" title's terminology *in the question*, something like *"to put it into another terms, my question seems to be: [crappy title text]"* usually works. This should make sure search engines will still link the question with the "crappy" terminolog / wording.

Comment: Closely related: [Should I edit titles which have nothing to do with the actual problem?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254216)

Comment: @Jeroen If they can't form a decent set of Google search terms for their programming problem, they have bigger problems than programming. Not to be unsympathetic, but StackOverflow's mission isn't to help everyone in every possible way. The goal is to create good, useful, *clean* content that educates people who come to the site.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I say absolutely yes fix the title, although there are some caveats.

Stack Overflow's primary goal is be a repository of good programming questions and answers that fit the scope of the site, which basically acts as a search engine magnet to draw users to the site who hope to find answers to their questions via their search engine of choice.

So what good does it do anyone when you have a title that does not accurately describe the problem?  An inaccurate or misleading title is going to result in some users not clicking the link because they don't think the question is about their problem, or cause them to click the link hoping it solves their problem, only to find it is about something completely different.

On top of that we have a brand new [triage review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage) whose sole purpose is to help to identify the quality of questions and appear to be leading toward helping make *meh* questions into good and maybe great questions.  The title is one of the most important things to fix a *meh* question because crappy/inaccurate titles don't attract positive attention.

Now the caveats:

- Don't waste your time trying to fix garbage.  If there is a lot more wrong with the question that can't be salvaged easily or without significant input from the OP, then wait for the OP to clarify before trying to start fixing the question.  Comment in these cases would be the best course of option.  Plus voting to close if one of the close reasons is applicable.
- If the actual issue is a duplicate, just vote to close, however, if the question already has picked up a **good** answer, then also fixing the title would be prudent to ensure the answer gets seen.
- Tread very carefully with brand new questions and make sure they are 100% clear and the actual issue is clear.  While fixing the title can help, it is also possible that you push a question down the wrong path with an incorrect evaluation of the problem.

Comment: `then leave it alone and wait for the question to be fixed enough to be worth it.` And then it will never get fixed. Closing it as a duplicate doesn't make the question suddenly not editable either. Editing it *ahead* of time may make the question no longer a duplicate.

Comment: @remyabel that did not come out as I really intended.  I've tried to clarify that point a little better.

Comment: @psubsee2003 IMHO, your first caveat is a valid point in a very general way. Questions sometimes need a few edits and/or comments before they are ripe for review or answering.

Answer (score 6):

You originally opened your question with:

> Every so often, people ask without having understood the real problem.

Don't edit the title to tell the OP what their "real problem" is. If the OP is mistaken about their problem, then use comments to point it out. Otherwise, if what you want to rectify is only that the title is not reflecting the contents of the question correctly, then edit the title. If the OP has a problem with it, point out to them that a better title means more chance that people who would find the question useful will look at it, and a better chance for the OP to get reputation.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I guess the "Every so often..." introduction with the "real problem" was not my primary concern so I replaced it with an alternate introduction.

Comment: I find this answer recursive.

Comment: I dunno. There's a fine line here. I recently ran across a post where the user was having trouble installing a Python package. The question was very poorly written despite all the details needed to answer being there, so I revamped it: new title, more clearly written, kept all the details. After my edit, the user claimed they knew how to install the package, even though all the errors they described were about installing the package. They later went on to accept my answer, which described how to install the package. Sometimes people say something without knowing what they're talking about. xD