# Should the title of duplicate questions be edited after a question is closed?

Tags: discussion, edits, duplicate-questions, title

Related: [Should a post title be modified to fit the problem?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278431/3920237)

While the above question is about editing question titles in general, I'm only addressing duplicates which have misleading titles and it is discovered *after* the fact. Let's take a hypothetical example (because I can't seem to locate the actual question):

A question about pointers is closed as a duplicate of a question which has "Function pointers" in it. The duplicate's question body says "this question is actually about all pointers". I vote-to-close as a duplicate of this question, leaving a comment explaining the misleading title.

Some advantages of editing the title:

- Users don't get turned away by the misleading title.
- The question title, which seemingly has gone unnoticed for years, now matches the question body.

Some (potential?) drawbacks:

- A duplicate shouldn't be modified just because it answers another question.
- The edit could seemingly invalidate answers or comments, even if the answers address the issue.
- Leaving a comment on a years old question to change the question title may have no effect.

Comment: First, it's perfectly fine to make any and all comments obsolete. Remember they are ephemeral. Next, while the title on the target should imho reflect the actual problem, it's perfectly fine (and may even be advantageous) to have way-signs leading even those who haven't actually understood what their real problem is to the solution. So in conclusion, the dup-closed question should be cleaned up, but correcting common misunderstandings and mis-conceptions in the question itself, unless they are strictly side-issues, does not seem to serve a goal.