# Edit Canonical-ish Question Title

Tags: discussion, title

There is a highly viewed/voted Q&A which is used a *very* common dupe target as it solves a *very* commonly asked question by users new to the vagaries of HTML/CSS

[**How do I remove the space between inline-block elements?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Now, I recently Mjölnir'd a question which related to `display:inline-flex` since the basic issue was still the same.

I, almost instantaneously, received a comment that the target was not a dupe since `inline-block` is not the same as `inline-flex`.

This got me to thinking that the dupe target's title might, perhaps, need to be edited....perhaps to..

> **How do I remove the space between inline/inline-block/inline-flex etc elements?**

...or something similar.

I feel that this might be useful but I'm wary of editing such a highly ranked/rated question without peer review.

Am I being over-pedantic (title-wise) or too wary of editing a title to be more "inclusive".

Your guidance is requested.*

<sup>*Also for a "better" overall title...if the title change is "approved".</sup>

Related [Should a post title be modified to fit the problem?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278431/should-a-post-title-be-modified-to-fit-the-problem)

Comment: Note that whether you choose to edit the question or not, you can simply respond to the comment to say that the differences in the question aren't relevant to the answer, making the questions suitable duplicates.  And just keep in mind that even if you edit that one thing, people are always going to keep pestering you over even the tiniest and most irrelevant differences in order to argue that their question is different, even though the answer answers their question.

Comment: Which I did but it occured to me that the dupe target title could use an "update" to reduce the commentary...hence this question. :)

Comment: Not surprised this has come up. I don't fancy the idea of cramming every single possible inline-* keyword into the title since more inline-level display types are being added all the time, but I can't think of anything better than the already long-winded "How do I remove the space between inline-block or other inline-level container elements?"