# Renaming question title to reflect actual problem

Tags: discussion, title

I just answered a question that was titled: [Cannot build simple golang code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32900985/2282538).  I find the title to be quite broad, and the problem ended up being specifically about slice syntax.

Would it be appropriate to rename the question to something like "Cannot build golang slice" or something like that, so that more users can find it in the future?

Comment: Descriptive titles are good. I often edit titles to be more descriptive. Considering that this question is so recent (only 30 minutes old), I'd say go for it. Can always undo your changes after all.

Comment: If not duplicate, then very related: [Should I edit titles which have nothing to do with the actual problem?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254216/456814).