# What to do with a question that focuses on the wrong problem?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I've seen this question [Angular 2/4 how to add multiple headers to http post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671112/angular-2-4-how-to-add-multiple-headers-to-http-post)

The user feels like there's something wrong with Angular because it seems he can't add multiple headers to his POST request. He explains his problem well, shows his code and the error he gets.

People who replied failed to see that the issue isn't with Angular, but with CORS (the server just doesn't allow the request).

He then updates his question twice, by showing other things he tried, and adding lots of code. Of course the issue remain.

By now the question is very long, with lots of details and code that is really irrelevant to the real issue. The title also has nothing to do with the real issue.

What should be done? Should we modify the title? Should we remove the useless part of the question, or maybe add something at the top explaining what the real problem is, and that the code below probably works well?

Comment: If you know the answer, why would answering the question not be a good start?

Comment: Yeah, just answer it? Probably no need to edit the question, you never know what combination of keywords might lead others to it.

Comment: Possibly comment that you feel this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but really it's up to the OP. It's their question.

Comment: [A car with square wheels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254341/839601)

Comment: Just go forward with the Refiner badge!

Answer (score 19):

This is a standard conundrum on Stack Overflow. Fortunately, it's one that was foreseen and provided for in the fundamental tools of the platform.

The resolution is simple, if sometimes laborious, but it's sort of rewarding because it requires you to employ real expertise in understanding the asker's situation.

**Step 1**: Answer the question so that the OP can solve their problem, then
**Step 2**: *edit the bejeezus out of the question* so that the next person can find it too.

See also [Should I edit titles which have nothing to do with the actual problem?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254216/should-i-edit-titles-which-have-nothing-to-do-with-the-actual-problem)

Comment: The OP already understood there was some issues with CORS but didn't fully understood the implication. I added the `CORS` tag as well as left a comment. I just feel like anyone seeing the question will either be intimidated by the amount of text, or will waste time reading it.

Comment: They definitely will; if that came up in a search result for me, I'd probably glance at the wall of text and move to the next tab immediately. That's why I'm saying you should edit, **heavily**, if you want to do something long-term useful with the question. **Get rid** of everything that is tangential to the core problem.