# Remove "Help Please!" from titles?

Tags: discussion, edits, title

New users have a tendency to ask somewhat personal, topically basic questions and include in the title "Help! Please", etc. (unrelated to [simply bad titles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253766/do-we-have-an-epidemic-of-low-quality-titles)). Should new question reviewers clean up the title? i.e. "new user, please help! me with gcc installation" becomes "GCC installation basics".

Comment: We could probably auto-close all of them without too many false positives.

Comment: [Search for people interested](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22Help+Please%22+closed%3Ano+hasaccepted%3Ano).

Comment: @mysticial hmmm. Autoclose pro tempore and make a special review catagory?

Comment: If there are other problems to fix in a question, feel free to remove 'help please' from the question body too.

Comment: [The Far Side: "Wait! Wait! Cancel that. ... I guess it says 'helf.'"](http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lruac96lFL1qks7w3o1_1280.jpg)

Comment: That would be good to remove the postings that stat by "So....", or "I am a noob/newby/beginner..." too :)

Comment: @gunr2171 [Mods, brace yourselves](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3a%22Help%20Please%22%20closed%3ano%20hasaccepted%3ano%20duplicate%3ano%20is%3aquestion%20score%3a..1%20locked%3a0)

Comment: @rgett I think we need an xkcd for this.

Comment: @Mysticial I like that your comment has 42 upvotes :-D

Comment: If you want to do something about these questions, please for the love of God [don't flag them for mod attention](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255355/bad-title-flagging-spree-anyone).

Comment: There are approx. 7 of these questions per month in total, including already closed questions. Doesn't really seems to be a big problem, just remove the title. (71 months from first question appearance, 498 in total = 498/71 = 7.01).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It is noise. It doesn't say anything other than that the OP is panicking.

*Please* do remove it, but make sure you improve the whole post if you do. Don't let other glaring problems stand just to fix the title.

Comment: But that's how rep-whoring newbies get their rep! Every +2 counts!

Comment: But what if it's *URGENT?!?!*  Maybe the OP needs help *ASAP RIGHT NOW PLS!*

Comment: @roippi http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=16486833#16486833

Comment: @roippi when it's urgent, urgently ask them to fix the guaranteed-poor-quality question first (if they do, great. if they don't the onus is on them).

Answer (score 8):

Down vote them. This is a Q+A site. All questions are a request for help. To say "help please!" suggests the user has not read any of the introductory material about what this site is: a lack of research effort. They think they need to distinguish a question thread from a discussion thread.

Another interpretation is they want to indicate this is an *urgent* problem that they want [the Mechanical Turk](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232114/what-do-meta-se-users-mean-by-referring-to-se-as-a-mechanical-turk) to push to the front of the work queue. This suggests they are a selfish arse. Punish them with a down vote. In many cases the panicking asker has rattled off a poorly described question. It is a strong clue that the question body will not show research effort, and thus deserves a down vote.

But it is also likely to be unclear, or a duplicate they have not bothered searching for, or lack sufficient information to be answerable. So rather than thinking "this is superfluous text, which I should remove" when you see "help please!", you should think "it is likely this post should be closed, so I should examine it to see it that is so, and then vot-to-close if it is bad".

Merely editing out the "help please!" is unlikely to be enough. The words are such a strong clue that the question is garbage that just editing them out could be counter productive.  We should not give the impression that the panicking ignorant can rattle off poorly thought out, selfish, questions that the Mechanical Turk will transform into gold for them.

Comment: What I'd the mechanical Turk?

Answer (score 5):

I agree that the 'Help' in the title is usually noise and should be removed.

One user has taken it upon themselves to work on this.  I've reviewed a number of their changes, and I'm worried that they are not fixing the rest of the post sufficiently to earn their couple of points.

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4831894
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4831896
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4831867
- Etc.

I should add that I approve of (and approved) the changes made in:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4831821

Comment: I'm sure I read somewhere recently that fixing a title so that it represents the question better, and improves searchability, is considered good enough to be approved, without other changes.

Comment: Nothing wrong with those edits

Answer (score -6):

I don't know... Sometimes using 'Help me' or 'urgent' in title is helpful. It's quite a nice heuristic for low quality questions.

It would be nice if such words were added to heuristics for low quality queues.

However, the general rule is, you shouldn't edit unsalvageable questions, because you can't make them better (somehow the definiton of the word 'unsalvageable') but you can (from what I know) interfere with the queue, making closing/deleting/onholding more difficult.

Comment: Sigh ..if only all spammers would have "This Is Spam" in their title... If the question still does not make sense after removing every capitalized phrase, I happily downvote and/or closevote it.

Comment: @Jongware most of them do, they write 'you will never see this offer again' or similar nonsense.