# Bad-title flagging spree, anyone?

Tags: discussion, flags

It is quite possible to search for [a lot of *very* low-quality questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title:%22Help%20Please%22%20closed:no%20hasaccepted:no%20duplicate:no%20is:question%20score:..1%20locked:0) that probably ought to be deleted. Should we non-mods just go on a flagging spree?

Or better yet, just `$(".result-link").children().children().each(function(a){window.open($(this)[0].href);})`. Or does this just amount to spam for mods?

Comment: Why am I flagging these questions instead of just downvoting them/voting to close?  Or better yet - why don't I evaluate the question itself and see if it can be salvaged without the "help please" bit?

Comment: @Makoto Do mods see downvoted questions?

Comment: Mods see downvoted questions, as well as deleted questions/answers, and likely even deleted comments.  They've got super powers.  Of course, this brings me to a fine point - we should really only flag a question if it **really requires** moderator intervention.  We can downvote/vote to close a question if we deem it to be poor quality; why does a moderator have to get involved?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bad question titles are not our business. If you're so inclined, edit them, but please do not flag them just for that reason (unless you're flagging them for closure for the appropriate reasons — those are handled by the community and are not seen by us, and even then a bad title alone isn't a reason for a question to be closed).

And on a broader note, flagging sprees in general are a Very Bad Idea™. You should only flag problematic posts as you come across them. Don't go hunting for things to flag, especially not in bulk. You only have a limited amount of flags per day, and you'll be better off putting them into more pressing problems, such as new questions, and any other posts that you might come across while using the site.

Comment: Are downvoting sprees a good idea?

Comment: Well, [about that...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255751/downvoting-spree)

Comment: "And on a broader note, flagging sprees in general are a Very Bad Idea™. You should only flag problematic posts as you come across them." - then shouldn't we remove the review queue?

Comment: @sashoalm: You can "come across" problematic posts during review. Processing a review queue is not the same as actively looking for specific posts to flag *en masse*.