# Downvoting spree?

Tags: discussion

Okay, okay, I get it: [gratuitous flagging is not a good idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255355/bad-title-flagging-spree-anyone). Recently I've been doing something kind of stupid. I search up [a bunch of mostly bad questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title:%22Help%20Please%22%20closed:no%20hasaccepted:no%20duplicate:no%20is:question%20score:..1%20locked:0) and then I open all of them (`$(".result-link").children().children().each(function(a){window.open($(this)[0].href);})`), and then for each question, I take about 1 second to judge whether it is really bad:

- If it is, then I downvote it.
- If it is not bad but good enough to merit attention, I might fix the title and/or reformat it and vote up.
- `default`: I advance to the next question.

Before you criticize my recklessness, consider this: I've done this twice, and every time I open the "bad questions" search, I see mostly new content (c.f. before I started this practice, it was the same every time), so I must be *useful* (i.e. questions are being deleted). So, is this a good idea?

Comment: You might be better of trying the triage-queue some...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my opinion, this kind of automated reopening won't play well. Unless you are genius, one second of attention is not enough to judge if the question is bad or not.

You are doing good thing of paying attention to possibly low quality questions, but you are not paying enough attention to each individual question. I believe at least some of those questions could benefit if you not only fix title/reformat, but also rephrase to improve clarity of what's being asked and possibly answer the question.

Also, there are [review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) designed to pull attention to questions that really need some moderator attention, I believe you should already have access to them.